# How to reinstate videodev2.h in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiling, make, gpu-driver, opencv, undelete

While building OpenCV I accidentally linked the wrong header file.

Instead of linking `videodeh.h` like this :

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev libv4l-dev v4l-utils
$ cd /usr/include/linux
$ sudo ln -s -f ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```

I did accidentally linked `videodev2.h`, like this:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev libv4l-dev v4l-utils
$ cd /usr/include/linux
$ sudo ln -s -f ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev2.h
```

Now when I unlinked `videodev2.h` (`sudo unlink videodev2.h`) it removed the hearder file from `/usr/include/linux`.

I tried reinstating `videodev2.h` by installing `libv4l-dev` and `v4l-utils` (`sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev v4l-utils`) but to no avail. I also just straight up copied `videodev2.h` from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h), but that gives me this error while building opencv:

```bsh
In file included from /home/rafay/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp:235:
/usr/include/linux/videodev2.h:63:10: fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/compiler.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any help that can reinstate `videodev2.h` without reinstalling Ubuntu will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have installed the [`linux-libc-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=videodev2.h) package with this header?

Comment: @N0rbert yeah seems like its installed. Running `sudo apt install linux-libc-dev` shows `linux-libc-dev is already the newest version (5.4.0-42.46).` Should I uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: You may try the reinstallation by `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-libc-dev`. Also please note that OpenCV is presented in [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/opencv).

Comment: @N0rbert Yeah! Got it seems it's back! thanks a bunch. Now I'll try building again. If you put your answer in, I'll mark it accepted

Comment: I need to build some additional cuda related feature which the pre-build binaries don't have, so have to build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the manually removed [header file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=videodev2.h) back you have to install its package by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-libc-dev
```

Comment: Thanks! I successfully build OpenCV after reinstalling.